# String parsing with different length

Tags: java, string, parsing

i need to parse SWIFT message which looks like:
:15A:
:20:REFERENCE
:21:NEW
:15B:
:30T:

I need to parse it by :...: symbols. The problem is that between : can be 3 and 2 characters. Is that possible?

Comment: parsing should give like following:
String[][] b = {{":20:", "REFERENCE"}, {":21:", "NEW"}} and so on.
Split here is not the best variant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way out i have found is:

```
String s = ":15A: :20:REFERENCE :21:NEW :15B: :30T:";
String[] parsedString = s.split("[\b:]");
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use the [SWIFT WIFE](http://www.prowidesoftware.com/en/wife-documentation.html) library for Java.

Comment: I wich I knew about this library 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "15A: :20:REFERENCE :21:NEW :15B: :30T".split("\\:");
```

Answer (score 1):

While you are parsing the string, examine each char to see if it is a separator. Also try `String.split();`

Comment: Seeing that there is a library already, I suggest following darioo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method to obtain the values between the ':'

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what "SWIFT" is, but just from your description of the data stream above:

As others have said, split on the colon. Then in the resulting array you'll have to peel off pairs, i.e. you'll get the first code in [0] with its text in [1], the next code in [2] with its text in [3], etc. It should be straightforward to loop through the array and match them up.

Two potential catches:

1. Is it possible to have a colon in the data stream that is not acting as a deliminter? Like, is there some way to escape a colon so it can be treated as text? If so, depending on how the escape rules work, you're either going to need a more complex expression in the split or it may be impractical and you have to loop through the text character by character.
2. Can you confidantly state that there will not be errors in the input stream? Like, could there be missing colons or codes without accompanying data or whatever? If so, again, split may be too simplistic.

The worst case is always to fall back to just looping through the string with charAt, testing each character for a colon, and breaking it up that way.